# Define Sonata Admin dynamically

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

Is it possible to define Sonata admins dynamically? The problem is, I have n lists (or classifiers) which I want to create admin for, and I don't fancy the idea to create separate service for every list.

Example lists:

```
list_id item_id name
COUNTRY EST     Estonia
COUNTRY LAT     Latvia
COUNTRY LTU     Lithuania
LANG    ET      Estonian
LANG    LV      Latvian
...etc
```

Each list may have slightly different requirements (different validation rules for instance) and I would like to use default item Admin, with possibility to override it.

Or how would you do it?

Comment: My approach is to create an abstract admin class to manage this entity and add one `listId` property to differentiate the real admins with `createQuery` to separate each list. Thus, you have a whole admin for each list.

Comment: Now, dynamically... based on entity content, I'm not sure if it's possible in SonataAdmin.

Comment: @yceruto Sorry, I dont follow. Could you be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

### The quick way

You can simply add if-conditions in your ListMapper:

```
public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('id') // every Entity has this (for example)
    ;

    if ($condition) {
        ->add('country') // only if $condition is true
    }

}
```

But I dunno how you imagine to access you Admin. Different roles/routes?

### Use multiple Admins

A better approach would be creating an AbstractAdmin for your (Base)Entity and extending it for your use-cases (than you can add every Admin to your menue though). This would also easily allow you overwriting

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;

abstract class BaseAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    /**
     * default validation group
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $formOptions = array(
        'validation_groups' => array('default'),
    );

    public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->add('id'); // every entity gets this one (for example)
    }
}
```

Then just extend your admin:

```
class CountryAdmin extends BaseAdmin
{
    protected $formOptions = array(
        'validation_groups' => array('default', 'country'),
    );

    public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        parent::configureListFields($listMapper);
        $listMapper->add('country');
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I got your entity-examples correct, but it should show you how to define your BaseAdmin and extend multiple Admins (allowing adding/removing fields and validation-groups per Admin).

Comment: The "quick way" is not really what I'm looking for because if there are 10-20 lists the method will get quickly out of hands. Also configureListFields won't be the only one. In the end the class is one big if-else and this is not maintainable code. 2nd way is what I'm looking for but these Admins need to be defined as services too and my question was how to do that dynamically.